# Android database cursor behaving oddly

Tags: java, android, cursor

I have two buttons. One for previous and one for next sqlite database record.

Here is how i am trying to get the next record from the database.

```
public long getNext(int id,DataBaseHelper helper){

    Story story = new Story();

    Cursor cursor = story.getStories(helper, 0);

            //Updated code      

    cursor.moveToPosition(id);

    cursor.moveToNext();

    return cursor.getLong(1);

            //Updated code

}
```

The problem is that if the previous position i pass it is "1", the next position i get is "3". Why does it skip one record? It keeps on skipping one record every time. Please tell me if i'm doing something wrong since i'm new at this and i have looked everywhere but this specific issues seems to be happening to me.

UPDATE : Code edited to show a better approach(perhaps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have been a little wrong with the approach here. I was ignoring the fact that the cursor index starts from -1 and that the database index of my table starts from 1. So i had to subtract -1 from the `id` variable and it solved the problem :) Here is the code that worked for me.

```
public long getNext(int id,DataBaseHelper helper){

            id = id - 1;        

    Story story = new Story();

    Cursor cursor = story.getStories(helper, 0);

            //Updated code      

    cursor.moveToPosition(id);

    cursor.moveToNext();

    return cursor.getLong(1);

            //Updated code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `Cursor.getPosition()` starts to count from 0. So, the first record is at index #0, the second one at index #1, ...

Take a look at the official documentation : [Cursor.moveToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29)

Let take a look at your code :

(**id = 1**, for the example)

```
cursor.moveToPosition(id); 

// Cursor is now on the record #1, so the second one of the list

cursor.moveToNext();  

// Cursor is now on the record id+1 = #2, so the third one of the list

return cursor.getLong(1);

// Returns the value of the colon #1 of the third record 
// of the list : so the record at the index #2
```

Comment: Ok. I have removed movetofirst(). But it still jumps one record.

Comment: Ok man based on your response i have adjusted my code for id and it worked. thanks:)